# How i can create dynamically Components with a Control?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, controls, windows-runtime

Im writting an Application for Win8 with C# and Xaml.

I have an Control with an Control-Template, i can add Components statically to the Control-Template.

But when i add Them in the Code Behind like this:

```
                TextBlock Text = new TextBlock();
                Text.Name = "Text" + rand.Next(999999);
                Text.Text = info.Name;
```

The Textblock is not shown when i add the Control to an Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the newly created controls to the hosting control.  e.g., if you have a stackpanel you can add the textbox to it with something like

```
TextBlock Text = new TextBlock();
Text.Name = "Text" + rand.Next(999999);
Text.Text = info.Name;
myStackPanel.Children.Add(Text);
```

*note : untested, but I'm pretty sure the syntax is right*